# apply weighted.mean on 3 dimension array

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply a weighted.mean on a 3 dimension array.

test data:

```
set.seed(1)
arr <- array(round(runif(24, 0, 10)), c(3, 4, 2))
wgt <- matrix(round(runif(12), 1), c(3, 4))
```

If it was only a mean, I would do:

```
apply(arr, c(1, 3), mean)
```

That works, transform my (3 by 4 by 2) array into a (3 by 2) matrix exactly like I want. Now I want that to be the weighted.mean instead of the normal mean.

```
apply(arr, c(1, 3), weighted.mean, wgt)
Error in weighted.mean.default(newX[, i], ...) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

I guess that doesn't work probably because the weighted.mean doesn't work on matrix.  (I would need a mapply or something inside the apply).  Anyway, I thought I would make the weighted mean myself by multiplying first then summing like:

```
apply(arr, c(1, 3), "*", wgt)
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  0.9  1.2  1.8
 [2,]  3.6  0.8  3.6
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.0
 [4,]  0.4  0.8  0.8
 [5,]  2.7  3.6  5.4
 [6,]  2.7  0.6  2.7
 [7,]  4.5  3.5  3.0
 [8,]  0.6  1.2  1.2
 [9,]  1.5  2.0  3.0
[10,]  1.8  0.4  1.8
[11,]  7.2  5.6  4.8
[12,]  0.7  1.4  1.4

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  2.1  1.2  2.4
 [2,]  2.0  2.8  4.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.0
 [4,]  0.8  2.8  0.4
 [5,]  6.3  3.6  7.2
 [6,]  1.5  2.1  3.0
 [7,]  2.0  4.0  4.5
 [8,]  1.2  4.2  0.6
 [9,]  3.5  2.0  4.0
[10,]  1.0  1.4  2.0
[11,]  3.2  6.4  7.2
[12,]  1.4  4.9  0.7
```

The result doesn't have the dimensions I would expect.  Actually, I wanted:

```
for(i in 1:dim(arr)[3]) print(arr[,, i] * wgt)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.9  3.6  4.5  0.2
[2,]  1.6  1.8  4.2  1.6
[3,]  0.0  2.7  3.0  1.4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  2.1  2.0  2.0  0.4
[2,]  1.6  6.3  4.8  5.6
[3,]  0.0  3.0  4.5  0.7
```

Which at the end:

```
> temp <- array(NA, c(3, 4, 2))
> for(i in 1:dim(arr)[3]) temp[,, i] <- arr[,, i] * wgt
> apply(temp, c(1, 3), sum)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  9.2  6.5
[2,]  9.2 18.3
[3,]  7.1  8.2
```

I've tried every possible permutation of margin in my apply statement and none work.

```
apply(arr, c(1), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(2), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(3), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(1, 2), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(1, 3), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(2, 3), "*", wgt)
apply(arr, c(1, 2, 3), "*", wgt)
```

Any idea what's wrong and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Inside your `apply`, "wgt" is a passed as it is (a matrix) and calls like `weighted.mean(arr[1, , 1], wgt)` have to be evaluated, hence the error. You could simplify your code with `apply(arr * c(wgt), c(1, 3), sum)` or, even try the efficiency of `colSums(aperm(arr * c(wgt), c(2, 1, 3)))`

Comment: thanks @alexis_laz, it works.   I'm still puzzled why `apply(arr, c(1, 3), "*", wgt)` didn't work but your `arr * c(wgt)` works better anyway.  As for speed, with my real data, the culSums option is faster, but my data are not  voluminous enough to see to what extent it's faster.

Comment: Use `apply(arr, c(1, 3), deparse)` to see what part of your array is passed to `"*"` each time -- for each "i" and "k" you get a `arr[i, , k] * wgt` call evaluated.

Comment: That trick with deparse is very interesting, I've noted it for future use!  That allowed me to understand how to fix my code.  `array(apply(arr, c(3), "*", wgt), c(3,4,2))` is equivalent to your `arr * c(wgt)`.  Your code is still better but we see that apply worked but the dimension was lost.  Thanks again.